# Set NSButton enabled based on NSArrayController selection

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsarraycontroller, nsbutton

OK, so I've set up an `NSTableView` bound to `NSArrayController`.

Now, I also have an `NSButton` which I want to make it "enabled" when there *is* a selection, and disabled when there is nothing selected.

So, I'm bind `NSButton`'s Enabled to the Array Controller's `selection` with a value transformer of `NSIsNotNil`.

[image: NSIsNotNil Array Controller and NSButton]

However, it doesn't seem to be working.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of whether or not anything is selected, the `selection` property of `NSArrayController` returns an object (`_NSControllerProxyObject`). This is why your binding isn't working the way you expect, because `selection` will never be `nil`. Instead, I bind to `selectionIndexes`, rather than `selection`, and have a value transformer called `SelectionIndexesCountIsZero` implemented like so:

```
@interface SelectionIndexesCountIsZero : NSValueTransformer
@end

@implementation SelectionIndexesCountIsZero

+ (Class)transformedValueClass { return [NSNumber class]; }

+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation { return NO; }

- (id)transformedValue:(NSIndexSet *)value { return [NSNumber numberWithBool:[value count] > 0]; }

@end
```

Incidentally, you can still bind to `selection` if you wish, but it will require a custom value transformer. Apple state that: *If a value requested from the selection proxy [object] using key-value coding returns multiple objects, the controller has no selection, or the proxy is not key-value coding compliant for the requested key, the appropriate marker is returned*. In other words, to find out if there is in fact no selection, you need to (i) get access to the proxy object, (ii) call one of the methods of your *actual* objects, and (iii) test to see if the return value from (ii) is `NSNoSelectionMarker`. Doing it this way the key method of your value transformer would look like this:

```
- (id)transformedValue:(id)selectionProxyObject {
    // Assume the objects in my table are Team objects, with a 'name' property
    return [selectionProxyObject valueForKeyPath:@"name"] == NSNoSelectionMarker ? @YES : @NO;
}
```

`selectionIndexes` is the better way since it is completely generic. In fact, if you do this sort of thing a lot it can be a good idea to build up a transformer library, which you can then just import into any project. Here are the names of some of the transformers in my library:

```
SelectionIndexesCountIsZero
SelectionIndexesCountIsExactlyOne
SelectionIndexesCountIsOneOrGreater
SelectionIndexesCountIsGreaterThanOne
// ...you get the picture
```

Comment: Very nice explanation. Thanks a lot, I'm trying it out! ;-)

Comment: Excellent solution. I ultimately created a more generalized transformer named `CountIsNonZero` with the implementation `- (id)transformedValue:(id)value
{
 if (![value respondsToSelector:@selector(count)])
  value = nil;
 return @([value count]!=0);
}`, which I can use with virtually any collection object.

Answer (score 3):

I bind to selectedObjects.@count, rather than selection

Comment: Well, I love the logic behind your suggestion. However, how is it possible that it's not working for me? (Controller Key: `selectedObjects`, Model Key Path: `@count`)